# How do I create a module above App module in angular 12?

Tags: angular8, angular9, angular10, angular11, angular12

i have a Login module which contains login.html.
i want login to be the default module and login.html as the default opening page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in main.ts file you will have something like this

```
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

replace this with

```
import { LoginModule } from './login.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(LoginModule);
```

Comment: thanks, will try this. Also, how do i come back to App after login ?

Comment: Not very sure but just like any other page you can set route to your App..and then navigate to that route